# Grails profile plugin issue

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am working to add the Grails profile plugin the documentation says I should add...

```
log4j {
    ...
    logger {
        ...
        com.linkedin.grails = "info"
    }
    ...
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462916/grails-log4j-configuration-error-method-missing-when-configuring-log4j-logger) seems to suggest it should be something more like...

```
com.linkedin.grails "info"
```

But when I run that I get...

> Error | log4j:ERROR Property missing when configuring log4j: com Error
>   | log4j:ERROR WARNING: Exception occured configuring log4j logging: No
>   signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.grails() is applicable
>   for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [info]

Can someone help with what I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the order backwards. First comes loglevel, then comes the package.

```
info "com.linkedin.grails"
```